# Cron-Bash: How to babysit an app on linux

Tags: linux, bash, cron

So, I have an app that runs on linux.  Unfortunately, the app isn't as stable as it needs to be.  So, I need to babysit it and make sure it is working properly.  My app immediately forks out 6 processes.  I've come up with a scheme that works ok but I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this.  So, my script is run by a cron job 1 time every minute.  My script needs to:

1. Make sure the initial process is still running.
2. Make sure at list 6 forks are running.

Here is the script I have so far:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 #myprocess -s will return the status of the running process
 output=`myprocess -s`;

if [ "$output" != "No myprocess found." ] ; then
  myprocess_pid=`echo $output | cut -d":" -f2`;

  #checks if that pid is running
  myprocess_running=`ps | grep $myprocess_pid | grep myprocess`;

  #if the string is an empty string, means script isn't running anymore.
  if [ -z "$myprocess_running" ] ; then

    #fires it off
    echo "`date` - myprocess not running ...." >> /tmp/log/messages;
    myprocess;

  fi
else #it ain't running

   echo "`date` - output from myprocess -s: $output" >> /tmp/log/messages;      
   myprocess;

fi
```

How can this be improved?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If you have a short PID then `ps | grep $pid` could return a number of processes whose PID (or name, for that matter) is a substring of the PID you are looking for. Better to use `ps -p "$pid"`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `myprocess -s` can set a return code != 0; you can write

   ```
   if myprocess -s; then
        ... code-when-ok ...
   else
        ... code-when-failure ...
   fi
   ```
2. when you have the pid, you can look in `/proc/<pid>` instead of your `ps .. | grep ... | grep`
3. when you have the parent pid, you can `grep "^Ppid:[[:space:]]*$pid" /proc/*/status` and count output lines to determine number of child processes